# Return null in SUM if some values are null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null, aggregate

I have a case where I may have null values in the column that needs to be summed up in a group.

If I encounter a null in a group, I want the sum of that group to be null. But PySpark by default seems to ignore the null rows and sum-up the rest of the non-null values.

For example:

[image]

```py
dataframe = dataframe.groupBy('dataframe.product', 'dataframe.price') \
                     .agg(f.sum('price'))
```

Expected output is:

[image]

But I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sum` function returns NULL only if all values are null for that column otherwise nulls are simply ignored.

You can use conditional aggregation, if `count(price) == count(*)` it means there are no nulls and we return `sum(price)`. Else, null is returned:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupby("product").agg(
    F.when(F.count("price") == F.count("*"), F.sum("price")).alias("sum_price")
).show()

#+-------+---------+
#|product|sum_price|
#+-------+---------+
#|      B|      200|
#|      C|     null|
#|      A|      250|
#+-------+---------+
```

---

Since **Spark 3.0+**, one can also use [`any`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#any) function:

```
df.groupby("product").agg(
    F.when(~F.expr("any(price is null)"), F.sum("price")).alias("sum_price")
).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace nulls with NaNs using `coalesce`:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('product').agg(
    F.sum(
        F.coalesce(F.col('price'), F.lit(float('nan')))
    ).alias('sum(price)')
).orderBy('product')

df2.show()
+-------+----------+
|product|sum(price)|
+-------+----------+
|      A|     250.0|
|      B|     200.0|
|      C|       NaN|
+-------+----------+
```

If you want to keep integer type, you can convert NaNs back to nulls using `nanvl`:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('product').agg(
    F.nanvl(
        F.sum(
            F.coalesce(F.col('price'), F.lit(float('nan')))
        ),
        F.lit(None)
    ).cast('int').alias('sum(price)')
).orderBy('product')

df2.show()
+-------+----------+
|product|sum(price)|
+-------+----------+
|      A|       250|
|      B|       200|
|      C|      null|
+-------+----------+
```