# Do not ignore NULL in MAX

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null, max

Using this dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(None,), (1,), (2,)], ['col_name'])
df.show()
# +--------+
# |col_name|
# +--------+
# |    null|
# |       1|
# |       2|
# +--------+
```

calculating `MAX` ignores nulls by default:

```py
max = F.max('col_name').alias('col_name')
df.agg(max).show()
# +--------+
# |col_name|
# +--------+
# |       2|
# +--------+
```

Is there a way to aggregate using `MAX`, but not ignoring null values? If there's null, it should return null.

Comment: The question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769814/how-to-return-null-in-sum-if-some-values-are-null/65770739#65770739) :)

Comment: Thank you, I truly couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this, but it's quite verbose...

```py
max = F.when(F.expr("every(col_name is not null)"), F.max("col_name")).alias("col_name")
df.agg(max).show()
# +--------+
# |col_name|
# +--------+
# |    null|
# +--------+
```

Shorter syntax:

```py
max = F.when(~F.expr("any(col_name is null)"), F.max("col_name")).alias("col_name")
df.agg(max).show()
```